# How to exclude all routes except one in NestJs?

Tags: express, nestjs

Let's say that I have controller with two routes:

```
@Controller('events')
export class EventController {

    @Get('my')
    async getMyEvents() {
        return "A"
    }

    @Get(':eventId')
    async getEvent(@Param('eventId', ParseUUIDPipe) eventId: string) {
        return "B"
    }
}
```

and I need to exclude all routes except one which have param:

```
export class EventModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(AuthMiddleware)
            .exclude({path: 'api/events/:eventId', method: RequestMethod.GET})
            .forRoutes(EventController)
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, it also exclude route `api/events/my`, so how to avoid that ?

Comment: Why not use a `forRoutes` specifically for the route you want to hit? Or why not use an interceptor/guard instead?

Comment: Because in reality I have plenty of routes, so to list all of them in `forRoutes` would be very inconvenient

Comment: You could probably use a regex then instead of the direct path. Something like `new RegExp('api\/events\/[^me]*')`

Answer (score 0):

Add the routes in exclude. You want to exclude and the rest in for routes.

```
export class EventModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(AuthMiddleware)
            .exclude("*")
            .forRoutes({path: 'api/events/:eventId', method: RequestMethod.GET})
    }
}
```